# Extract nth-child with xml-lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to get the first `<bar>`'s text node with [xml-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-lens-0.1.6.3/docs/Text-XML-Lens.html) from an XML like this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    I want ONLY this!
  </bar>
  <bar>
    I DON'T want this!
  </bar>
</foo>
```

In other words, I want to write a lens expression equivalent with XPath `/foo/bar[1]/text()`

First, I wrote a haskell script like below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Lens
import           Text.XML.Lens
import           Text.HTML.DOM
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TIO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- TIO.getContents
  parseLT input & toListOf (root . el "foo" ./ indexing (el "bar") . index 0 . text) & map T.fromStrict & T.unlines & TIO.putStr
```

But Actually got **both first and second** `<bar>`'s texts:

```
> stack runghc sample.hs  < input.xml

    I want ONLY this!


    I DON'T want this!
```

Isn't this possible with current xml-lens implementation?
Should I submit an issue to xml-lens or some other project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior.

`indexing` assigns indices to targets of a traversal; `el` has at most one target so only 0 will be given.

You may want to use `el "foo" . indexing (plate . el "bar") . index 0` or `el "foo" . elementOf (plate . el "bar") 0` instead. These handle multiple occurrences of `"bar"`.